# CKEditor textarea created with display:none

Tags: ckeditor

I have recently cloned a script, and while the CKEditor text area in the original works fine, the one in the new script does not.

The original script has the following code:

```
<td align="left" valign="top">Description: <a target="_blank" href="faq_bb.php#edit"><img title = "<?= $bb_help; ?>" alt="<?= $bb_help; ?>" height=17 width=19 border=0 src="/images2/query_icon.gif"></a>
</td>
<td valign=top align="left" colspan=2>
<?php
    $winsize = strlen($bb_desc);
    if ($winsize < 255)
    {
        $editorheight = 10;
    }
    else
    {
        $editorheight = 20;
    }
    $text = html_entity_decode($bb_desc, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
    <textarea name="_bb_desc" cols=<?= $editorheight ?>>
        <?= $text ?>
    </textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      CKEDITOR.replace( '_bb_desc');
    </script>
 </td>
```

The new script has:

```
<td align="left" valign="top">Description: <a target="_blank" href="faq_bb.php#edit"><img title = "<?= $bb_help; ?>" alt="<?= $bb_help; ?>" height=17 width=19 border=0 src="/images2/query_icon.gif"></a>
</td>
<td valign=top align="left" colspan=2>
<?php
    $winsize = strlen($bb_desc);
    if ($winsize < 255)
    {
        $editorheight = 10;
    }
    else
    {
        $editorheight = 20;
    }
    $text = html_entity_decode($bb_desc, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
    <textarea name="_bb_desc" cols=<?= $editorheight ?>>
        <?= $text ?>
    </textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      CKEDITOR.replace( '_bb_desc');
    </script>
 </td>
```

Viewing the rendered page in the Web Console Element Inspector, the original script produces:

```
<iframe src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" title="Rich Text Editor, _bb_desc" aria-describedby="cke_87" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The new script produces:

```
<iframe src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none !important;" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" title="Rich Text Editor, _bb_desc" aria-describedby="cke_72" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true" hidden="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The 2 scripts execute in the same environment, using the same version of CKEditor (4.5.3.Full).

Any suggestions as to what might be causing the different behaviour would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution, although I am no more aware of what the issue was than before.

It appears that the issue was caused by the name of the script. If it was called tracker.php, CKEditor did not function correctly. Changing it to, apparently, anything else, solved the problem.

Weird.